# How to return serverAnswer?

Tags: java, android, android-volley

How do I return `serverAnswer` behind `onResponse`?

Because in `onResponse`, `serverAnswer` gets data, but behind `onResponse` it's an empty variable...

For example, if I try to show a Toast with `serverAnswer` in `onResponse`, it's alright, `serverAnswer` has data from JSON string. But if try to show a Toast with `serverAnswer` behind `onResponse` - I get an empty Toast.

And `addUser` returns an empty String too.

```java
public String addUser(final String username, final String email, final String password, final Context context) {

    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(
            Request.Method.POST,
            REGISTER_URL,

            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(final String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        final JSONObject status = jsonObject.getJSONObject("Result");
                        serverAnswer = status.getString("Server answer");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    serverAnswer = error.getMessage();
                }
            }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put(KEY_USERNAME, username);
            params.put(KEY_EMAIL, email);
            params.put(KEY_PASSWORD, password);
            return params;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    requestQueue.add(request);

    return serverAnswer;
}
```

Comment: I would imagine that when you do `return serverAnswer;` then request has not even completed yet

Comment: `onResponse` is the very place where you should take care the response from server.

Comment: `onResponse()` is a Callback, it's called when the request is finished, if you try to access `serverAnswer ` from a place out of `onResponse()` there is a big chance, it's still empty, so `onResponse` is the correct place to handle `serverAnswer`, or you can make a method in your class, or in a class, and call it with param `serverAnswer `, something like `handleAnswer(serverAnswer );`